# CPU timer and php microtime

Tags: php, linux, timer

I am interested to know if there is better way to time operations. Relying on timer, as it seems the microtime .. or any other method that reads OS time will clearly not give as good an estimate.
I am interested to know in general what is the precision of timing operations nowadays in a linux based operating system, say Red Hat Linux.

Now to be more specific, I recently wrote an algorithm and tried to compare the time it took. My php code worked like this :

```
$start = microtime(true);
$result = myTimeConsumingProcess();
$end= microtime(true);

$timeinMiliSec = 1000.0*($end - $start);
```

It turns out that sometime the process took 0 ms and on different execution, with precisely the same data it took 9.9xxxx milliseconds.

The explanation for this as I can imagine is that time is measured using timer interrupts. If the execution starts and finishes before the next timer interrupt updates the time of the OS, we are bound to get 0 sec as the difference.

It used to be the case from my early DOS days that a timer interrupts was called at every 18.19 ms.  Looks like that is not the case any more with better machines and upgraded OS , we have are now running timers faster than that.

Comment: The system clock is the only way that the system can tell time. I suspect you're stuck with all its limitations.

Comment: There's a big difference between the elapsed time for a process to complete and the CPU time it uses - that's why there's there a `time` command in Unix (and Linux). But with regard to your experiment, you are clearly near the limits of your measuring apparatus. The solution is to measure to lots of items rather than a single one (i.e. run myTimeConsumingProcess() in a loop a thousand times and compare the results with an empty loop).

Comment: btw you might wanna use HRTime extension to get more precise results